# list index out of range in my coding

Tags: python

Can anyone help me fix this error I keep getting please. I have tried to look for a solution but I can't find any. Below is the error message and also part of my coding

```
Please enter your class Y or X or Z: Y
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/LIAM'S USB/DEV6 FINAL.py", line 118, in <module>
score=int(items[1])
IndexError: list index out of range


results={
start=True
while (start):
    pupil_class=input("\nPlease enter your class Y or X or Z: ")
    if pupil_class == ("Y"):
            classfile="Class_Y_results.txt" 
    elif pupil_class == ("X"):
            classfile="Class_X_results.txt" 
    elif pupil_class == ("Z"):
            classfile="Class_Z_results.txt" 

    f=open(classfile,'r')

    for line in f:
            items=line.split(',')       
            name=items[0]
            score=int(items[1])                
            if name in results:
                    results[name].append(score)                        
            else:
                    results[name]=[]
                    results[name].append(score)

    f.close()
```

Comment: To debug, right after `for line in f:` add `print(repr(line))` and see what the offending line looks like.

Answer (score 1):

A certain line in your `Class_Y_Results.txt` only has one entry (not separated by commas), hence the list returned by `items=line.split(',')` only has a length of 1 (or maybe 0), causing `score=int(items[1])` to throw an `IndexError`.

Sample:

```
>>> a = "foo,bar"
>>> b = "foo"
>>> len(a.split(','))
2
>>> len(b.split(','))
1
>>> a.split(',')[1]
'bar'
>>> b.split(',')[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an empty like in one of your files. This will not contain a comma, so you will not have an `item[1]`, and this produces the error message you see.

Check how many fields you get back from the split to solve this.